# Usar valor modificado dentro de IF em outra variável

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho uma condição de valor que é alterado dentro de IF e precisava usa-lo em outra opção chamada por menu, como posso executar?

```
from datetime import datetime

print("Bem-vindo usuário!")

menu = print('[1] Entrada/Saída\n[2] Estado atual de veículo\n[3] Vagas disponíveis')

iniciar = int(input("Digite opção para iniciar: "))

data = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M dia:%d/%m/%Y')

vrestantes = 100

vagas = 100

if 1==iniciar:
    while (vrestantes > 0):
        carro = input("Digite placa: ")
        acao = int(input("[1]Entrada ou [0]Saida?: "))

        if acao ==0:
            print("Saída do carro {} às {}".format(carro,data))
            vrestantes = vrestantes + 1
            print("Total de vagas disponíveis: {}".format(vrestantes))
            if vrestantes > 100:
                print("Vagas não podem ser maiores que 100 por limitação de espaço")


        else:
            if acao ==1:
                print("Entrada do carro {} às {}".format(carro,data))
                vrestantes = vrestantes - 1
                print("Total de vagas disponíveis: {}".format(vrestantes))
```

caso eu queira acionar uma outra opção no menu (ex:3) para imprimir o valor que foi alterado, teria como?
no caso eu queria usar a função vrestantes e imprimir ela com um valor atualizado

Answer (score 0):

No python usamos o elif para adicionar condições. Com três opções ficaria assim:

```
if acao == 0:
    ...
    ...
elif acao == 1:
    ...
    ...
elif acao == 2:
    ...
    ...
```